# Why array.sorts sorts parent array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

why is the array `"matrix[0]"` sorted too, Systemcopy required?

```
int[] check = matrix[0];

Arrays.sort(check);
```

Now I use Systemcopy to Fix this, but why?

Comment: Because `matrix` is an array of references to `int[]` arrays, essentially

Comment: *Now i use systemcopy to Fix this, but why?* Because `int[]` **isn't** a primitive type.

Comment: Your question doesn't include enough information. We shouldn't suppose that `matrix` is 2D array. Also `arrays.sorts` doesn't really point to something everyone knows. Can you please edit the question?

Comment: `int[] check = matrix[0]` does not copy the array `matrix[0]`, it just copies the reference to the array (i.e. it's a shallow copy). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480 . FYI, you can also use `matrix[0].clone()` to create a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line: `int[] check = matrix[0]` assigns a **reference** of the `matrix[0]` to `check`.  Which means that whatever operation you do on `check` will be reflected in the `matrix` as well.  Though the references are not the same, the memory locations are, unless you create a copy (like you mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

When you do `int[] check = matrix[0]`, `check` is now referencing `matrix[0]`. To make them two different arrays you need to make a deep copy.